# Python implementation of Quicksort fails to sort the entire array

Tags: python, quicksort

I have the python code below for the Quicksort algorithm. The code works fine until all elements towards the right of the pivot are greater than the pivot, in which case, these remain unsorted.

In theory the code should sort all elements in the array, but at this stage I do not know what I am missing

```
def swap(array, i, j): 
     temp = array[i]
     array[i] = array[j]
     array[j] = temp

def choosePivotFirstElement(array, left, right):
     return left

def partition(array, pivotIndex, left, right):
      swap(array, pivotIndex, left) #put pivot to the left
      pivot = array[left]
      i = left + 1

     for j in range(left+1, right+1):
           if (array[j] < pivot):
                  swap(array, i, j)
                  i = i + 1
     swap(array, left, i-1) #put pivot back to its place
     return (i-1) #return the position of the pivot

def qsort(array, left, right):
        if ((right - left) < 2):
           return

      pivotIndex = choosePivotFirstElement(array, left, right)
      split = partition(array, pivotIndex, left, right)

      qsort(array, left, split)
      qsort(array, split + 1, right)
      return array

myList = [7,2,5,1,29,6,4,19,11]
sorted = qsort(myList,0,len(myList)-1)
print sorted
```

this should return

[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 11, 19, 29]

instead returns

[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 29, 19, 11]

I am new to python, so I might me making a fairly obvious mistake.

Comment: `qsort` isn't returning anything... it seems to sort in-place. Isn't your `print` statement showing `None`?

Comment: are you sure about this `((right - left) < 2)` condition? at first glance it looks like it would prevent your sort to work on, say `qsort([1, 0], 0, 1)`

Comment: Also, swaps in python ca be accomplished via `x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]` where `x` is your list.

Comment: This is clearly an assignment for the coursera's algorithms course.

Comment: You really should not be needing numpy for something like this.

Comment: Cameron, sorry, I forgot the "return array" at qsort.

Comment: Daniel, I just looked for a method to calculate a simple median and this is where I ended up, numpy.median...

Comment: Anyway Cameron, can you see where the code is failing? (or anyone?)

Comment: @Javier: There's at least one more bug besides the `< 2`: `right` is a valid (inclusive) index, but `range()` expects an exclusive maximum; so `range(1, 3)` will only yield `1 2`. You need to fix your call to `range` in `partition`.

Comment: @Cameron: You are my most favourite person right now. T-h-a-n-k-y-o-u!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't even looks like a python code, you are still trying to translate from something to python and that's not a good idea.

Usually you would have something like this in Python:

```
def quickSort(arr):
    #Leftside
    less = []
    #pivot
    pivotList = []
    #rightside
    more = []
    #if the length of the array is one. then, there is no point in sorting it
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return arr
    else:
    #sorting :)
        #Defines the pivot as the first element
        pivot = arr[0]
        for i in arr:
            #for each element in the array verify:
            if i < pivot:
                less.append(i)
            elif i > pivot:
                more.append(i)
            else:
                pivotList.append(i)
        #Define the Lists less (left side) and more (right side)
        less = quickSort(less)
        more = quickSort(more)
        #Return the actual array
        return less + pivotList + more

a = [7, 2, 5, 1, 29, 6, 4, 19, 11]
a = quickSort(a)
print a
```

## EDIT

There are several mistakes in your code as pointed out by commentators:

You should *not have a swap function*, as you can do

```
array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
```

Since you are not calling in this example either choosePivotLastElement or choosePivotMedianofThree so, you should not post them. You could ask about specific things later on, in other questions.

Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

The range should be **range(left+1, right+1):**

And I have an impression that:

`if ((right - left) < 2)` should be something like I used in my code:  `if len(array) <= 1:`

Later in your code you can see that you don't define other lists, and you don't return nothing. Please, look at my code again and try to understand it. You might ask questions about specific details, **but you really should try to understand it.**

Comment: step by step Kyllopardium. There are parts in your code I don´t understand! :) but looks very nice. Anyway, can you spot where my code is wrong? (btw, I forgot the "return array" for qsort)

Comment: ok, I´ll get on it. The code up there has been updated (I am also new to stackoverflow), since I inmediately noticed the lack of a return in qsort and someone told me about the exclusive nature of the range function in python. The truth is that, in a broad brush sense, I do undertsand your code. However, it uses a partition method different than mine (there are various partition methods). The partition method I should use should only act if the element found is less than the pivot, if not "do nothing". Anyway, I will save your code and have a good look later. Thanks.